# SF novel featuring a quest, very flexible roads, and giant letters floating out of mountains

Tags: story-identification, novel

SF novel, probably from the eighties. Dying Earth sub-genre and actually compared to Jack Vance in the plaudits (the main reason I remember buying it). Features a quest, very flexible roads, and giant letters floating out of mountains (I think).

Comment: Does this look familiar? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_Crash

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could be [Dark Is The Sun](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/303429) by Philip Jose Farmer.

'The flying figures,' the Yawtl said.
The Shemibob
said, 'Some of the figures are letters which humans
used in their writing from the beginning.'

Comment: wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Is_the_Sun

Comment: It does have flexible roads: *This highway, for instance, had existed long before Deyv's great-great-great-great-grandfather was bom, and probably many generations before that. But it was not overgrown with plants, nor had trees been able to tear it apart. The green life, except for a short grass, encroached but withered when within sixty feet of the road. Floods sometimes washed out the earth beneath it here and there. By some magical means, earth sifted back under it and packed down. Earthquakes twisted it, but as time went on, it straightened out.*

Comment: *However, there were vast movements of the ground that even this wonderful substance couldn't resist. Deyv had heard that far down the road, a mountain had grown up under it, and the road ran straight up the elevation and over it. The substance should have snapped apart in many places, but it had merely lengthened.*

Comment: I really liked PJF until I encountered that book when it first came out. My brother and I called it "Bad Is The Book".

Comment: Many thanks: I think the nail has been hit. 